# PropertyEditorSupport method not executed

Tags: spring-mvc

i want use spring mvc convert json to one object like

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "searchPolygonArea/", method = RequestMethod.GET,params = {"region != null"})
    public @ResponseBody ResultBean <List <Spot>> searchPolygonArea(@ModelAttribute (value="regionModel") Region regions,@RequestParam(value="region") Region region){
        return new ResultBean <List<Spot>> ();
    }

    @InitBinder(value="regionModel")
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder,@RequestParam(value="region") final String regionParams){//,
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor (Region.class, new PropertyEditorSupport (){
            Region value ;
            @Override
            public Object getValue () {
                return new Region ();
            }
            @Override
            public void setAsText (String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                System.out.println (text);
                try {
                    value = JSONUtils.json2Obj (text, Region.class);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


});
    }
```

but setAsText and getValue not executed , i don't know why.

Comment: Did you checked that whether your control comes in initbinder?

Comment: yes ,it execute registerCustomEditor ,but the @requestmapping not execute getValue  and setAsText  method

Comment: The `PropertyEditor` will only be caled when converting from request parameters to fields of a model object, it will not be called for mapping request parameters. If you want that you have to write a converter, in this case a `String` to `Region` converter and register it with the `ConversionService`.